# setting linker options in qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.5

I compiled qt 5.5.1 statically using the following options:

```
configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc2013
```

and now when I am trying to compile a simple hello world program that doesn't use any qt libraries (just plain c++ app).

The problem is that I can't set the linker options for the program to use static msvc libraries using the /MT flag. I am adding this to project file:

```
CONFIG += static
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -O2 -MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG += -Zi -MTd
```

I get the following error:

```
msvcprt.lib(locale0_implib.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for     'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
```

and

```
:-1: warning: LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the clean command didn't delete the MAKEFILE.RELEASE so I had to go delete the file manually and qmake generated a new file with correct -MT parameter.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serve me correctly, this is a problem you will meet also frequently when you use visual studio. So modify the build configuration as shown in the warning message, add NODEFAULTLIB preprocessor in build command please.

Comment: ok I've recompiled Qt and the error is gone but it still compiles the program as dynamic linked not static linked, tried the NODEFAULTLIB too.

Answer (score 0):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O2 -MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -Zi -MTd
```

also you can try

```
LIBS += -lLIBRARY /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried that but still not compiling statically linked program, this is the compile output `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
 cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -I..\hello_cpp -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1.2\5.5\msvc2013static\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.56044.16.jom
main.cpp`

Comment: you can see it was passing -MD parameter when compiling even when I added -MT in the .pro file, anyway I've found a workaround and wrote it. Thanks for your help.